# What is this postgres syntax? rows=([[:digit:]]+)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I ran into this syntax  `rows=([[:digit:]]+)` while working, and I am not even sure what to google to go look this up in the documentation. Can someone tell me what this is called?

For reference, the whole function this comes from is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_estimate(query text) RETURNS integer AS $$
    DECLARE
    rec   record;
    rows  integer;
    BEGIN
    FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN ' || query LOOP
        rows := substring(rec."QUERY PLAN" FROM ' rows=([[:digit:]]+)');
        EXIT WHEN rows IS NOT NULL;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN rows;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT;
```

Comment: `' rows=([[:digit:]]+)'` is a [regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) supported by PostgreSQL. Please note however that `substring` returns text while variable `rows` is integer, so a cast is needed.

Comment: It's a [regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) that is trying to extract the (estimated) number of rows from the execution plan. Nowadays it's probably easier to generate the plan as JSON and use a JSON function to get the value directly rather than trying to parse the output of `format text`

Answer (score 0):

Per @Stefanov.sm and @a_horse_with_no_name, this is postgres' implementation of regex. Thank you!